# Контроль Event.eventPhase в пользовательских деревьях

Tags: javascript, typescript

#### Описание

Вот есть класс для событий в JavaScript - `Event`. И так же другой класс принимающий эти события - `EventTarget`.
Создал у себя класс наследовав `EventTarget`:

```
class Entity extends EventTarget {
    name: string;
    parent: Entity;
    children: Entity[];
}
```

И собственно потом создаю обычное дерево из этого класса. Так как у класса Event есть функция погружения (capturing) и всплывания (bubbling) думал переписать `dispatchEvent` так, чтобы и у моего дерева выполнилось погружение и всплытие события.
Ну, собственно как-то так:

```
class Entity extends EventTarget {
    name: string;
    #parent: Entity | null = null;
    get parent(): Entity {
        return this.#parent ?? (() => {
            throw new ReferenceError(`Parent entity is null`);
        })();
    }
    children: Entity[];
    dispatchEvent(event: Event): boolean {
        if (event.eventPhase === Event.CAPTURING_PHASE) {
            try {
                if (!this.parent.dispatchEvent(event)) return false;
            } catch (error) { }
        }
        if (event.eventPhase === Event.AT_TARGET) {
            if (!super.dispatchEvent(event)) return false;
        }
        if (event.eventPhase === Event.BUBBLING_PHASE) {
            for (const child of this.children) {
                if (!child.dispatchEvent(event)) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Вопрос

Так вот свойство `eventPhase` всегда стоит на `Event.NONE` и это нельзя изменить, так как оно только для чтения.
**Как я могу контролировать `Event.eventPhase`, чтобы реализовать погружение и всплытие в собственном дереве?**

#### Пример

Пример максимально упрощён для легкого понимания.

```
const e1 = new Entity();
const e2 = new Entity();
e1.children.push(e2);
const e3 = new Entity();
e2.children.push(e3);
e1.addEventListener(`test`, (event) => {
  console.log(`Event ${event.type} from e1 at phase ${event.eventPhase}`);
});
e3.addEventListener(`test`, (event) => {
  console.log(`Event ${event.type} from e3 at phase ${event.eventPhase}`);
});
e2.dispatchEvent(new Event(`test`, { bubbles: true }));
```

При запуске должен выводится в консоль.

```
Event test from e1 at phase 1
Event test from e3 at phase 3
```

Comment: Можете показать пример использования класса и собственно dispatchEvent

Comment: @SwaD добавил. Пример максимально упрощен. Не обращайте внимания на родителя, который изначально `null` и.т.п., потому что у меня, в полном коде все эти проблемы решены.

Comment: похоже этого [сейчас нельзя](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/583) реализовать на своем дереве.

Comment: @Grundy придется создать собственный `EventTarget` (¬_¬ )